# date-and-time library compile pattern error

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using public date-and-time npm package in my app as follows.

```
  var date = require('date-and-time')
```

Following that i create a promise like so.

```
exports.handler = async (event)=> {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var pattern = date.compile("h:m:s")
        var now = new Date()
        var time = date.format(now,pattern,false)
    })
   await Promise.all([promise])
}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: formatString.replace is not a function
at Object.date.format (/var/task/node_modules/date-and-time/date-and-time.js:147:29)
at /var/task/index.js:635:25
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Library Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time
Library function looks like this:

```
    /**
 * formatting a date
 * @param {Date} dateObj - a Date object
 * @param {string} formatString - a format string
 * @param {boolean} [utc] - output as UTC
 * @returns {string} a formatted string
 */
date.format = function (dateObj, formatString, utc) {
    var d = date.addMinutes(dateObj, utc ? dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() : 0),
        formatter = locales[lang].formatter;

    d.utc = utc;
    return formatString.replace(/\[[^\[\]]*]|\[.*\][^\[]*\]|([A-Za-z])\1*|./g, function (token) {
        return formatter[token] ? formatter.post(formatter[token](d, formatString)) : token.replace(/\[(.*)]/, '$1');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Promises.

Your library expects a string, but you pass it a compiled regex.

Something like this should work, though:

```
var pattern = "h:m:s"
var now = new Date()
var time = date.format(now,pattern,false)
```

Comment: let me try that, although the link shows the proper way of using the library is with compile

Comment: wow it works!! So weird they have outdated documentation on their page!!

Comment: Apparently supporting compile is only supported in version 13 and I'm using version 12!